# Is there a simple way to code the strategy (or other) design pattern in ANSI C that would fit on the screen of an 11" MacBook Air?

Tags: c, oop, design-patterns

It seems that OO in ANSI C is not the favored approach to OO today. Does anyone know of a way to code a simple design pattern using strict ANSI C so I can prove to a friend that it is possible?(Axel-Tobias Schreiners' book got me going on this!)

Comment: You can program anything you want in C, you just won't necessarily have any native support for it.  I would suggest taking your favourite design pattern, attempting to implement it, and then asking a specific question if/when you get stuck.

Comment: +1 for referencing Axel!  He was my grad instructor at RIT.

Comment: Wait, where does the laptop come into this? Seriously, I'm just confused now.

Comment: I just think it could be really small and amazing, I am trying a simple delegate pattern first, not really C proficient though.

Comment: Delegation is just the OO sugar of a simple callback. About the screen, a 11" Mac Book Air has the same resolution as an old 17" lamp shaped iMac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OO using C can indeed be implemented using function pointers as explained quite well in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/840501/1158895).

Using the info from that post, here's how I would implement a Strategy pattern in C using basic inheritance.

Lets use the following C++ as a guide:

```
class StrategyBase
{
    ...
    StrategyBase();
    virtual void strategyMethod() = 0;
    ...
};

class StrategyDerived
{
    ...
    StrategyDerived();
    void strategyMethod();
    ...
};
```

And here is the corresponding C code:

```
typedef struct StrategyBase_t StrategyBase;
struct StrategyBase_t
{
    StrategyBase *base; /* must be first memeber */
    void (*strategyMethod)(const void *self);
};
StrategyBase *newStrategyBase();
void strategyMethod(const void *self);  /* the abstract method */

struct StrategyDerived
{
    StrategyBase *base; /* must be first memeber */
    void (*strategyMethod)(const void *self);
    /* more derived attributes here */
};
typedef struct StrategyDerived_t StrategyDerived;
StrategyDerived *newStrategyDerived();
```

And here are the function implementations:

```
void strategyMethod(const void *self)
{
    /* If called with just a StrategyBase, strategyMethod will be NULL, *
     * so perhaps some sort of protection should be added here first    */
    ((StrategyBase*) self)->base->strategyMethod();
}

void strategyMethodDerived(const void *self)
{
    /* Put your implementation here */
}

/* StrategyBase constructor */
StrategyBase *newStrategyBase()
{
    StrategyBase *self = (StrategyBase*) malloc(sizeof(StrategyBase));
    self->base = self; /* See comment below about virtual table */
    self->strategyMethod = NULL; /* StrategyBase is abstract, right? */
    return self;
}

/* StrategyDerived constructor */
StrategyDerived *newStrategyDerived()
{
    StrategyDerived *self = (StrategyDerived*) malloc(sizeof(StrategyDerived));
    self->base = newStrategyBase();
    self->strategyMethod = self->base->strategyMethod = strategyMethodDerived;
    return self;
}
```

The virtual table implementation is **very** basic, but should work. Ideally, something more robust should be implemented.

Then you just have to use a pointer to StrategyBase in a Struct that needs a strategy, and there you have a strategy pattern implemented in C. I havent tried compiling it, but this should serve as a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to it; instead of a class `Foo`, use a `struct foo`; instead of a constructor `Foo::Foo(...)`, have a function `struct foo *foo_new(...)`.

For a real-life example, see the venerable [GObject library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GObject).

Comment: Ya, but I think its more interesting to see how to use inheritance with C.

Comment: Inheritance is not a requirement for object-oriented design. (And it can still be done in C, with some effort.)